# avoiding div(s) wraps

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a div parent container having fixed width (say width: 300px), which contains divs (say width: 80px). But when the container get 4 divs (i.e. 80*4=320px > 300px), it wraps the forth div. I want that there would be no wrapping of divs, instead we can perform horizontal scrolling, so that container width remain 300px, and if divs get out of vision, we may horizontally scroll to see all divs.

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="parent" style="width:300px;overflow:scroll;">
    <div class="child" style="width:80px; float:left;">lorem</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:80px; float:left;">ipsum</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:80px; float:left;">dolore</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:80px; float:left;">lorem</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.child {
   display: inline-block;
}

#parent {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/qnpGm/

UPDATE:
in ie6/ie7 this will work only on elements with a natural display: inline.
Thanks for comments :)

Comment: Thanks Ivan, it worked, also had to remove "float: left;". <html>
<body>
  <div id="parent" style="width:300px;overflow:scroll;white-space:nowrap;">
    <div class="child" style="width:80px; display: inline-block;
">lorem</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:80px; display: inline-block;
">ipsum</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:80px; display: inline-block;
">dolore</div>
    <div class="child" style="width:80px; display: inline-block;
">lorem</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: yup, was going to suggest this next :p

you may want to consider setting the child divs to spans as IE doesn't like using inline-block on tags that aren't already inline tags

Comment: you will need to watch with this though as IE6 and IE7 will not render it as other browsers do.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `white-space:nowrap;` to your #parent style. Haven't tested this on your code, but I've used this in similar situations where I've needed to expand a div containing a number of child divs without setting a width for the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Hence "inline-block" will come up with problems regarding crossbrowser-compactibility (IE 6), I guess this isn't possible without a bit of extra markup.

So let's assume "parent" is your viewport. Then you'll need a container, wrapped around the "child"-elements, having the same width as all of them - in your case 320px. You can calculate the with using either server-side languages or javascript.

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="parent" style="width:300px;overflow:scroll;">
    <div id="view" style="width:320px;">
        <div class="child" style="width:80px; float:left;">lorem</div>
        <div class="child" style="width:80px; float:left;">ipsum</div>
        <div class="child" style="width:80px; float:left;">dolore</div>
        <div class="child" style="width:80px; float:left;">lorem</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```